# Layout with a Table inside ScrollPane and an Image

Tags: java, libgdx

I want a simple layout with an Image on top of a ScrollPane (with a table inside).
The ScrollPane works great but the problem is that the scale of the Image is wrong (my image has a circle inside and it becomes oval).

Here is the code:

```
   batch = new SpriteBatch();
   stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);

   Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/uiskin.json"));
   Texture textureButton = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image.png"));
   Image imageButton1 = new Image(textureButton);
   Image imageButton2 = new Image(textureButton);

   Table t = new Table();
   for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      t.row();
      t.add(new Label("TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST" + i, skin));
   }
   ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(t);

   Table container = new Table();
   container.setFillParent(true);
   container.row().expand();
   container.add(imageButton1);
   container.row();
   container.add(scrollPane);
   container.layout();
   container.debug();

   stage.addActor(container);
```

I am totally lost :(

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
```

change it to true:

```
stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);
```

[Scene2d Viewport](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#viewport)

If false:

> The stage will be stretched to the viewport, potentially stretching the stage's aspect ratio.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but changing false to true doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to NateS (from Badlogic Games forum), the solution is to set a minWidth to the image:

```
table.add(image).minSize(Value.prefWidth, Value.prefHeight);
```